# Signalr in localhost with android studio and genymotion

Tags: android, localhost, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I want to run signalr in my localhost, but i dont know why only in machine does not work, when i use my hosting xxxxx.xxxxxxx.com works like a charms, this is my code:

```
  public void connect() {

//    private static String serverUrl = "http://xxxxx.xxxx.com/"; THIS WORKS

      private static String serverUrl = "http://192.168.56.1:8080"; //THIS DOES NOT WORK

        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        Log.d(TAG, "starting connection...");           

        mConnection = new HubConnection(serverUrl, "", true, new NullLogger());

        Log.d(TAG, "H creating proxy...");
        mScheduleHub = mConnection.createHubProxy("chatHub");

        Log.d(TAG, "H connection.start()...");
        ClientTransport clientTransport = new ServerSentEventsTransport(mConnection.getLogger());
        SignalRFuture<Void> awaitConnection = mConnection.start(clientTransport);

        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "H started");
            awaitConnection.get();
            Log.d(TAG, "H got");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"H InterruptedException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,mConnection.getConnectionData());
            Log.e(TAG, "ExecutionException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
```

I'm getting microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.http.InvalidHttpStatusCodeException: Invalid status code: 404 exception.

I try to change my localhost to:

```
http://192.168.56.1
http://192.168.56.1:8080
http://192.168.1.29 (static ip)
http://192.168.1.29:8080
http://10.0.3.2
http://10.0.3.2:8080
http://127.0.0.1
http://*:8080
http://+:8080
```

but nothings works, can anyone help me?

Comment: In your PC/laptop, use web browser, can you access `http://192.168.56.1:8080` or not?

Comment: yes, i can with 192.168.56.1 and 10.0.3.2.

Comment: Pls check if it can be accessed from the web browser in the phone / emulator or not?

Comment: yep, i can access from the web browser without problem.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of that web browser in the phone / emulator? Moreover, post full logcat information

Comment: `http://192.168.56.1:8080` is IIS 7.5 or IISExpress? Pls check your IIS config, I guess that it can be `http://192.168.56.1:8080/signalr` or something equivalent